# I can not add this library in android studio: compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'

Tags: android, gradle

When I added this library  `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'` in my dependencies , I got below errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
Error:(253) Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\Jamshidi\AndroidStudioProjects\School\School\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(257) Attribute "rippleColor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(257) Attribute "rippleColor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(253) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 26.882 secs
Information:5 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

How can i solve it:

My `build.gradle` file consist below content:

```
 dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
   compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
   compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
   compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0'
   compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

Comment: are your sdk and build tools updated?

Comment: yes, i think it is not sdk and tool error . it is Error:(257) Attribute "rippleColor" already defined with incompatible format.

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've got this error because `'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`
and     `'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'`
libraries have the same attribute `rippleColor`

To solve this conflict you can:

1. clone one library(`com.android.support:design:22.2.0` or `com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar`), rename the attribute, import to your project.
2. Replace the  third party library with [this](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon) or [this](https://github.com/rey5137/material) or others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is straight forward. As Milad said, both the dependencies are using the same attribute, and while compiling and forming a merged .XML file the compiler is facing an issue.

Try referring this 
https://github.com/vajro/MaterialDesignLibrary

Hope it works.